# Refactor such as winForm.exe calls a .DLL

Tags: c#

I have a windows application (winForms). I would like to refactor it such that all functionalities are built to .DLL file so that when winForm is run, it will just call .DLL. In addition, I would be creating another .exe which is Console App so when a user wants to just "schedule task" it, he will create a config file that will run the console app, which when run will also call .DLL

I don't have much knowledge about refactoring and compiling projects to .DLL (I hope I am making sense)

I just want to know if I am correct on how I quite understand it for now:
Should I transfer all my functionalities from winForms to a class that will be compiled to .DLL? Or if I am wrong, what should I put in a .DLL class?

Comment: Put UI stuff in the form and algorithmic, data, etc. in the DLL. That's a good design principle anyway - keep the GUI as thin as possible and separate out the logic and data.

Comment: You should definitely do some experimentation and research creating and using dlls before you modify your project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should create a new project in your solution. Create a class library project in your solution in Visual Studio (or tool of choice, you did not specify what you are using so I assume VS).

To add a new project, right click your solution and select `Add` submenu, then `New project`.

From the categories menu on the left, select Visual C#, then Windows, and Class Library.

[image: create new project dialog in VS]

Then you should add a reference to this new class library project from your current WinForms project.

Right click `References` in your current WinForms project and select `Add reference`.

Then select `Solution` category on the left (VS2012), or `Projects` tab (VS2010) and Select your newly created class library project from there.

[image: add class library reference]

Then you can start moving classes from your current WinForms project to this new class library project. Class library project will be compiled as a dll and you will have access to all classes in this dll from your WinForms project.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing dramatic is needed.  Just Project + Properties, Application tab, change the Output type setting from Windows Application to Class Library.  Done.  You may have to declare a class *public* if you didn't already do that.  You could remove your Program.cs source file since it won't be used anymore but that is entirely optional.  A good reason to not remove it is keeping your project testable.

Fwiw, changing the Output type setting is not actually necessary, .NET doesn't distinguish between a DLL and an EXE at all.  The CLR loads assemblies by their display name, it doesn't include a filename extension.  You can add a reference to your EXE assembly in another project and it will work just fine.

So doing nothing at all already works :)